# Using mod_rewrite to Redirect All URLs to Secure, No Subdomain, and a Subfolder, with Exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to redirect all requests to:

Requirement 1:
https protocol, a particular subfolder, and no www subdomain.

So, for example, "http://www.example.com" redirects to "https://example.com/subfolder/"

Requirement 2:
Requests for pages within the subfolder should not redirect to the root subfolder.
ex: "http://www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder2/"redirects to "https://example.com/subfolder/subfolder2/"

Requirement 3:
Reqs 1 & 2 should happen for all requests except the robots.txt file, located in the root directory (so, the following urls will not redirect):

- "http://example.com/robots.txt"
- "http://www.example.com/robots.txt"
- "https://example.com/robots.txt"
- "https://www.example.com/robots.txt"

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
# anything not a file or a directory goes to subfolder root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301]

# non secure http protocol redirects to secure
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/subfolder [R=301]

# root redirects to subfolder root file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subfolder/index.php [R=301]

# www subdomain is redirected to domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]

# Last check to redirect with entire trail, not sure if this ever catches a request.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Yet the example.com/robots.txt file is being redirected to the subfolder.

Comment: Add at the top: `RewriteRule ^robots\.txt - [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my full solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ https://example.com/subfolder/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```